# Search for specific characters

Tags: java

I am writing a code that loads an ArrayList of Strings and checks to see if a specific word is used. This may sound weird but the specifics are:

Number of toots containing "toot" (with any capitalization and allowing zero (0) in place of oh (o), e.g., "to0t" should be counted too); however, you should not count a toot if it only contains "toot" as part of another work, e.g., "tooter" is not enough to count a toot.

I have tried many things but it doesn't seem to work...

Here is what I wrote:

```
for (String toot : toots) {
    toot.toLowerCase();
    toot.replace("0", "o");
}
tootsWithToot = 0;
for(int i=0; i<toots.size(); i++){
    if(toots.get(i).contains("toot ") || toots.contains(" toot ")
                                      || toots.contains(" toot.")
                                      || toots.contains(" toot")
                                      || toots.contains("toot")){
        tootsWithToot++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: It doesn't count the right results, it reads words like "tooter" as a "toot"

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable

```
toot.toLowerCase();
toot.replace("0", "o");
```

does nothing, you have to assign it back to toot

```
toot = toot.toLowerCase();
toot = toot.replace("0", "o");
```

Comment: How so? Back into the ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ListIterator to do this better. Keep iterating and inserting the processed String back.

```
        /**
         * Preprocess the list
         */
        ListIterator<String> iterator = toots.listIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String toot = iterator.next();
            iterator.remove();
            iterator.add(toot.toLowerCase().replace("0", "o"));
        }                
        int tootsWithToot = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<toots.size(); i++){
            if(toots.get(i).contains("toot ") || toots.contains(" toot ")
                    || toots.contains(" toot.")
                    || toots.contains(" toot")
                    || toots.contains("toot")){
                tootsWithToot++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ListIterator (still a novice) would this be all I need?

Comment: Yes! all this piece of code assumes is that toots is an ArrayList<String> which is what you mentioned in your question.. Best is to try it with your data set and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. hope code explains ..

```
      int tootsWithToot = 0;
      for (String toot : toots) {
        toot  = toot.toLowerCase().replaceAll("0", "o").replaceAll("toots", "toot");
      //here add anything which need to skip..
        if(toot.contains("toot"))
        {
            StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(toot," "); 
           /*space is token  
             [ suppose toot. it will not pass if u want to pass toot. than  
             add in replaceAll("toot.", "toot") just make all passed strings to 'toot'] 
           */
            while(str.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                if(str.nextToken().equalsIgnoreCase("toot"))
                {   tootsWithToot++; break;}
            }

        }               
    }
   System.out.println("tot:" +tootsWithToot);
```

Comment: Yours worked for one, but not for all. It didn't work for the sentence: "hello toot hello"
which it should have counted

Comment: Can you specify  all input scenarios .. ?

Comment: Each line is a separate message


"1 toots 2 t00ts"

"toot"

"will be back"

"tooter tooting"

The results should show 2 as tooter and tooting aren't the word "toot" with or without the O or 0 variations.

Comment: I hate to sound hasty, but since you seem to know what you're talking about, would you mind us entering a chat room or skype?